# Is it possible to send a pointer to function via socket?

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, function-pointers

I have two processes of the same program, possibly running on two different machines.
I'd like the process P2 to receive a function pointer from process P1 via socket.
Is is possible? Is it a good practice?

EDIT: more interesting would be to send the code of the function too, but I'm skeptic about this. Would it be possible?

Comment: _"Is is possible?"_ No. _"Is it a good practice?"_ No.

Comment: It is possible in a non-portable way. Still definitely not good practice. (Consider what happens if one of your machines is "hacked"?)

Comment: Sending the code of a function is also possible (but even more un-portable).

Comment: @immibis do you have references where I can find material about this? (portability and security are guaranteed in my environment, so it's not a problem)

Comment: Since portability isn't a concern, what platform are you running on? (This should be in the question)

Comment: @immibis I added a tag linux

Answer (score 6):

You *can* send a function pointer from one process to another, the same way you can send a pointer to some other object.

The problem is that the pointer may not actually point to the function *as it exists in the target process.* Especially if the OS is protecting itself with things like [ASLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization).

You could also send the code across, provided you had some way of figuring out where it ended, and that it was position independent code, and that your environment allowed you to write arbitrary data to memory and then call it.

But, to be honest, there are better ways to achieve what you seem to want, such as the use of RPC (remote procedure calls), in a more portable manner.